# Liferay Upload : UploadPortletRequest empty

Tags: upload, request, liferay, portlet

I am having an issue getting multiple file from an upload using the UploadPortletRequest.
I can see in my ActionRequest that the files are here: using debug i see that actionRequest.multipartFiles.[0].fileItem.tempFile give me the location of the first uploaded file.
Though, in order to get the multipartParameterMap I need to convert the ActionRequest in UploadPortletRequest. when I do :

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
```

My uploadRequest.getSize("fileName")) returns 0...

Do you know what could be the cause?
Do you have another solution to get the temp uploaded files from the ActionRequest ?

Here is the .jsp I use :

```
 <portlet:actionURL var="fileUploadURL">
    <portlet:param name="formAction" value="fileUpload" />
 </portlet:actionURL>



<form:form name="fileUploader" commandName="springFileVO"
method="post" action="${fileUploadURL}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label> Select a File</label>

    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" value="<liferay-ui:message key="upload" />" onClick="<%= uploadProgressId %>.startProgress(); return true;"/>
</form:form>
 <liferay-ui:upload-progress id="<%= uploadProgressId %>" message="uploading" redirect="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(fileUploadURL) %>" />
```

Here is the Controller :

```
@ActionMapping(params="formAction=fileUpload")
public void fileUpload(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){

    UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
     System.out.println("Size: "+uploadPortletRequest.getSize("uploadedFile"));
```

[...] }

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you uploading a file with the literal file name "fileName" (that you try to get the size for)?

Comment: Actually, my goal is just to retreive all the file that have been uploaded. My request object has the path in the temp directory but I cant get it from there. Then I am doing something wrong with the UploadPortletRequest I guess. But I dont really understand how it is supose to work. Any advices ?

Comment: I edited the "fileName" that was wrong with the "uploadedFile"

Comment: Got it,  <input type="file" name="<portlet:namespace/>uploadedFile" multiple="multiple">. You are missing portlet:namespace attribute

Comment: I'm not using this API day in&out, but had the feeling that the name you give is rather a filename(?) Correct me if I'm wrong... You might want to inspect the `uploadPortletRequest` object in a debugger to see what parameters and attributes it actually has. And yes, it might as well be the missing portlet namespace, I'm seconding Rajesh.

Comment: There is a "multiple" parameter that allows you to upload several file. So the name can not be a file name (I guess...). The problem I have is that the uploadPortletRequest doesn't contain my files, though the actionRequest does. But i am not able to get the information needed from the actionRequest, I can only see it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing portlet:namespace attribute.

```
<input type="file" name="<portlet:namespace/>uploadedFile" multiple="multiple">
```

As your uploading multiple files, you can use following.

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
File[] files = uploadPortletRequest.getFiles("uploadedFile");
for (File file : files) {
    System.out.println("Size: "+ file.length());
}
```

Comment: File[] files = portletRequest.getFiles("uploadedFile"); can you change to uploadPortletRequest.getFiles("uploadedFile");

Comment: Got it,  <input type="file" name="<portlet:namespace/>uploadedFile" multiple="multiple">. You are missing portlet:namespace attribute

Comment: can you replace <form:form name="fileUploader" commandName="springFileVO"
method="post" action="${fileUploadURL}" enctype="multipart/form-data">  with <form action="${fileUploadURL}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">. Because you mapped springFileVO with it.